# Getting -1 from bit field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wrote this

```
select ISNULL((select convert(bit, null) ), -1)
```

and expected `-1` as result but got `1` instead.... Why? due to that bit I guess but Why?

and how can I get `-1` from a bit field if its NULL?

Comment: Coincidentally, what's wrong with `NULL` in your situation?

Comment: `select coalesce(cast(null as bit), -1)`?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44407/1

Answer (score 7):

Bit can only be 0,1 and `NULL`.

Also 0 is false, everything else is true.

Have a look at the results of

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/32071)

```
select ISNULL((select convert(bit, null) ), -1) Returns1;
select ISNULL((select convert(bit, null) ), 1) Returns1;
select ISNULL((select convert(bit, null) ), 100) GuessWhat_Returns1;
select ISNULL((select convert(bit, null) ), 0) Returns0;
```

And the most important part

from [bit (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx)

> **Converting to bit promotes any nonzero value to 1.**

Comment: +1 - you make an important point, because converting 2 to bit (which is 10 in binary) also returns 1, so it is not converting by doing `value & 1`.

Answer (score 2):

A field with a data type of `bit` can only be 0, 1 or NULL.  As such, by converting to bit, you restrict it to one of those three values. `ISNULL(cast(BitColumn as int), -1)` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the -1 you're specifying is the "replacement value" if first parameter in ISNULL is actually null.  You're the one specifying what should be returned.

Make sense?

Read here: [ISNULL() T-SQL Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You get `1` for the same reason that the following returns `1`:

```
select cast(-1 as bit)
```

A `bit` contains only one bit, so it cannot represent `-1`.  The options are `0` and `1`.  On modern computers, `-1` is typically represented as all `1`'s, so the fact that it becomes `1` makes sense.

Comment: But this throws an error  select CAST(256 as tinyint)

Answer (score 1):

Cast it to int:

```
select ISNULL(CAST((SELECT CONVERT(bit, NULL) ) AS INT), -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This returns null

```
select convert(bit, null)
```

These all returns 1

```
select convert(bit, -1) 
select convert(bit, 2)
select convert(bit, 3)
```

I suspect it is tying to cast the -1 to a bit as part of the isnull

But this throws an Arithmetic overflow error

```
select CONVERT(tinyint, 256)
```

Astander has the answer.
Converting to bit promotes any nonzero value to 1.
Bit is not necessarily stored as a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ISNULL(CAST((SELECT CONVERT(bit, NULL) ) AS INT), -1)
```

THIS gives you the right anwser.

Comment: we are all fighting for `bit`!

Comment: bit!, bit, bit, where is the bit?

Comment: I will make changes @BhupeshC

Answer (score 0):

You are all wrong 
**here is how is done :**

```
select (ISNULL((select convert(bit, null)), -1))-2
```

Just joking !

**Bit can only be 0,1 and NULL.** Like @astander said 
*When you will find a bit with more values - you will be the next Bill Gates*